# Как убрать нижний отступ в textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как убрать нижний отступ в `textarea` ?

```js
$('textarea').css("height", $("textarea").prop("scrollHeight"))
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  resize: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a </textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте к стилям textarea:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c8tuogg6/

Нижний отступ - это горизонтальный скроллбар.

Answer (score 0):

```
margin: 0; // убрать отступы
padding: 0; // убрать поля
```

Comment: Как видите не помогло.

Comment: Вы про пустую строку снизу? Это не отступ.

Comment: Да про неё, а почему появляется эта строка?

Comment: Определитесь с тем чего именно вы хотите.